# Go template missingkey option always return error

Tags: go, go-templates

So the question seems to have been asked a couple of times before, but none of the previous answers worked for me, I go from errors to errors to no results.

So as I am most certainly missing something that I don't see I would like for some help:

```
res, err := os.Create(strings.Replace(f, ".tmpl", "", -1))
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}

t, err := template.ParseFiles(f)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}

removes = append(removes, res.Name())

config := make(map[string]string)
for _, v := range vars {
  config[v] = os.Getenv(v)
}

err = t.Execute(res, config)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}

res.Close()
```

So to explain what I am doing, I'm passing a string to a file (path/file) that has a yaml.tmpl extension. The result file should be yaml so I remove the last part to generate the result file name.

I then parse the file with go template and then I execute with a configmap that I generate.

This is working fine like this but I would like to add: `.Option("missingkey=error")` to have it generate an error in case I don't give a value from the configmap to a variable in the template.

So I tried to add the options in the template parse file like this:

```
t, err := template.New("test").Option("missingkey=error").ParseFiles(f)
```

But I can't use template Exectute and have to use template ExecuteTemplate but with those I get:
`template: no template "test" associated with template "test"` or `template: test: "test" is an incomplete or empty template`

In the rare cases I don't get an error, it just ignore the option like if I do this:

```
err = t.Option("missingkey=error").Execute(res, config)
```

Does anyone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I updated the code with the answer of Cerise Limon and here is the playground: [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wcIdaA7xvBu)

Currently that playground just ignore errors and do the template even if the config passed is empty and there is no or condition in the template.

Comment: Replace "test" with the name of the template in the parsed files that you want to execute.

Comment: You mean giving it the name of the template file in the f variable? I tried that and I get the exact same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ParseFiles method](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template.ParseFiles) documentation says:

> Since the templates created by ParseFiles are named by the base names of the argument files, t should usually have the name of one of the (base) names of the files.

Use [filepath.Base](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Base) to get the base name of the file. Use that name as the name of the template:

```
 t, err := template.New(filepath.Base(f)).Option("missingkey=error").ParseFiles(f)
```

[Run an example on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zswNzTIeMpY).

Comment: As I said in the other comment, I tried that, and that doesn't work, it just gives me the same error as I have with any name.

Comment: I have a stupid question, it seems that in fact it does not work... I don't have any error when I don't inject any values in the template using your method... Shouldn't it generate an error in case I don't have any value injected?

Comment: So I finally understood how this works... The option never check if you have a null value in the configmap, it only checks if the key exists in the configmap... So as I always created it, I never had any error!!! The stupid thing is that if you have the configmap key non existing but with an or declaration and a default value, you still are in error...